# Filtering dataframe based on "Date" specific (<1 day or 24 hours)

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

i am filtering the data frame based on dates...now how to get the data with same dates in last month?

```
df<-data.frame(
  Date=sample(seq(as.Date('2018-10-25'), as.Date('2018-11-20'), by = "day"), 100,replace = T),
  category1=sample(letters[1:6],100,replace = T),
  count=sample(1:1000,100,replace = T)
)

df%>%filter(Date < Sys.Date()-1 & Date >= Sys.Date()-8) %>%group_by(Date,category1)%>%summarise(Total=sum(count))


Output:
# A tibble: 19 x 3
# Groups:   Date [?]
   Date       category1 Total
   <date>     <fct>     <int>
 1 2018-11-13 a           231
 2 2018-11-14 e           763
 3 2018-11-14 f            50
 4 2018-11-15 a           643
 5 2018-11-15 e           745
 6 2018-11-15 f           931
 7 2018-11-16 b           712
 8 2018-11-16 e           416
 9 2018-11-16 f           914
10 2018-11-17 a           270
11 2018-11-17 b           837
12 2018-11-17 d          1539
13 2018-11-17 e           251
14 2018-11-18 a          1181
15 2018-11-18 f           966
16 2018-11-19 a           673
17 2018-11-19 b           960
18 2018-11-19 d           768
19 2018-11-19 e           932
```

above ouput is with Nov 13 th to Nov 19 so how to get the data in same dates of October month?

Comment: I think you might be looking something like this -Date <- as.Date(seq(as.Date(Sys.Date())-8 ,as.Date(Sys.Date())-1, by="days"))

Comment: @RonakShah updated please check

Comment: @Hunaidkhan code updated can u please help

Comment: ok will try with that

Comment: @Hunaidkhan but that will vary from month to month right..i am running the daily automated reports so dates want to be compare the exact last month dates

Comment: ok i understand every month you need data from 13th to 19 th

Comment: no no no @Hunaidkhan suppose i am runing the reports daily basis,,,for tomorow report it will vary and day after tomorrow dates will vary

Comment: you are confusing me, you want rolling dates right? for every month what is the past dates you want which will be changed in daily basis

Comment: exactly sir...dates will going to change daily basis

Comment: provide the date range ( like previous 30 days to 45 days of data) thats what i am asking , what is the date range as your question tells want to find out dates for October , please specify it clearly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you can subtract 1 month from the current filter condition.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  filter(Date < (Sys.Date() - 1 - months(1)) & 
         Date >= (Sys.Date() - 8 - months(1))) %>%
  group_by(Date,category1) %>%
  summarise(Total = sum(count))
```

This will give you rows for the same dates in October.

Comment: ..superb buddy..i expected the ans from u..thank u so much

Answer (score 0):

Do be careful in using "months" since it subtract the quantity from the month in the date.  It will cause problems if the new value does not have that many days in the month; e.g., subtracting 1 from 2018-03-31

```
> x <- ymd(20180331)
> x
[1] "2018-03-31"
> x - months(1)  # the 31th of February does not exist
[1] NA
```

Comment: so what is the best solution u r suggesting?